# Javascript quiz: radio button score validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, radio-button

I'm learning javascript, and for a class assignment I'm working on a simple quiz. Found here: http://redwood.colorado.edu/scho5922/dm2/projects/project1.html

My problem is that I can't get the radio buttons to validate correctly. This prevents the quiz score from being calculated. When you click enter it cycles through the questions, but choosing the correct answer doesn't increase the score. I've tested this by adding both an alert after the if statement and a button that displays the 'score' variable. There is no alert with the correct answer and the score button (not on current version) displays a score of 0.

JavaScript

```
<script>
    var beers =[
  ["New World Porter", "Avery"],
  ["Ellie's Brown Ale","Avery"] ,
  ["Out of Bounds Stout","Avery"] ,
  ["Hazed & Infused Dry Hopped Ale", "Boulder Beer"],
  ["Sweaty Betty Blonde Ale", "Boulder Beer"],
  ["Mojo IPA", "Boulder Beer"],
  ["Mama's Little Yellow Pils", "Oskar Blues"],
  ["Dale's Pale Ale", "Oskar Blues"],
  ["G'Knight Imperial Red Ale","Oskar Blues"],
  ["Old Chub Scotch Ale","Oskar Blues"]
  ] ;

var score = 0;
var questionNum = 0;
var turns = 0;

function enterF (beer){   

questionNum++;
turns++;
var question = "What brewery makes ";
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML= question + beers[questionNum][0];
var answer = document.getElementsByName("beerbut").value.checked;
if(answers[i].checked == beers[questionNum-1][1]){
score++;
alert(score);
}

}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body onload="popup()">

<h1 id="header">What brewery makes New World Porter</h1> 

     <div class="buttons">
<form>
<label for="_avery"> Avery</label>
<input type="radio" name="beerbut" id="_avery" value="Avery">
<br><br>
<label for="_bb"> Boulder Beer</label>
<input type="radio" name="beerbut" id="_bb" value="Boulder Beer">
<br><br>
<label for="_oskar"> Oskar Blues</label>
<input type="radio" name="beerbut" id="_oskar" value="Oskar Blues">
<br><br>
<label for="lefthand"> Left Hand </label>
<input type="radio" name="beerbut" id="_lefthand" value="Left Hand">
<br><br>
<input type="button" name="enter" id="enterbut" value="enter" onClick="enterF()">

</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The alert and if statement references aren't in the code you posted, it will help to see that

Comment: you call enterF() on your button without any arguments. is there any script you forgot to post?

Comment: ok the arguments have been added. The solution posted below increases the score counter but it does so regardless of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get a value from multiple elements at the same time. That's not how you do it.

Change this in the javascript

```
var answer = document.getElementsByName("beerbut").value.checked;
```

For something like this

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("beerbut");
for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
   if(elements[i].checked){
        alert(elements[i].value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok it's working perfectly now. I added the score button so you can check the score at any time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually upon further testing, the score counter will increase even if the wrong answer is entered. For example clicking left hand 10 times will return 100%, even though there is no question with that answer. The link in the OP has been updated

Comment: That was not the idea of the example. I was showing you that you have to get the values by single not by group, sorry, I should had make that clear